# Cut or trim audio with wade form view and save it

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, audio-player

i want to cut or trim audio with wade form view and save it. But i haven't found a way to solve this problem yet. Thanks for helping me

i try library android-audio-visualizer, and ffmpeg to trim audio. but it's not my expected